# Rails: searching filter model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, full-text-search, filtering, categories

I need to add filter search feature in my search form.
It's something like a social network. My app has societies, and a societies have categories (fashion, press, factory, ecc). I need my search to filter those categories.

Since I saw there are a plenty of search gems (solr, thinking sphinx, elasticsearch, sunspot) and look through all of them is a bit overwhelming have anybody accomplished such a task?
Any suggestion?

Things the search form should perform:

1) Search for a Society Name (And I can handle this with Sunspot) 
2) Filter all Society by category chosen by user in a select tag (something like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option)) 
3) And if both the text field and the select are filled, search for the name only in the category chosen

Comment: Hard to say without deeper knowledge about your application and the architecture. There are several comparisons around. Also I suggest having a look at the related Railscasts: http://railscasts.com

Comment: Thanks but I have already checked them. Application is simple: many societies, everyone categorized and I want to search for category.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't want to use a gem, that you want to roll this out on your own and want guidance to how to do it?

Comment: Edited question, and I totally want to use a gem. What I'm trying to say is that I can handle simple text search but don't if I can filter my search the way I specified in the question

Answer (score 0):

A great gem that I found recently is [Ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack), which Ryan Bates has a [RailsCasts for](http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack).

Here is an example of how it's used.

```
<%= search_form_for @query do |f| %>
  <!-- filter: `society_name` contains text -->
  <%= f.label :society_name_cont %>
  <%= f.text_field :society_name_cont %>

  <!-- filter: `category_id` equals -->
  <%= f.label :category_id_eq %>
  <%= f.collection_select :category_id_eq, Category.all, :id, :name %>
<% end %>
```

If you're unfamiliar with `collection_select` the Rails Guides will help <http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease>.